# “ls” shows no files in mounted NFS folder, but “cd” works

Tags: linux, bash, mount, nfs

An NFS share was mounted to `/vol/mynfs` on a Linux client. It does not show any folders with `ls` and bash completion does not work in `/vol/mynfs` too. But after changing to a subdirectory all files are visible.

```
$ ls /vol/mynfs
total 0
$ cd /vol/mynfs/test
$ ls  # shows all files as expected now.
```

Why are the files invisible first and how can I make them always visible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I presume that your NFS share is automounted, yes?

Before the share is actually mounted, `/vol/mynfs` is just an empty directory, so `ls` shows it as that.  Moving to that directory forces the mount to actually happen, so the `ls` after that shows the contents of the now-mounted directory.

The files will be listable as long as the share is actually mounted.  If the share is subsequently unmounted (manually or automatically, after an inactivity timeout), the directory will appear to be empty again.

Something like `(cd /vol/mynfs; ls)` will force the mount and do the `ls`, if that's what you need to do for some reason.

Comment: Yes autofs mounted file dont show up until you do cd.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have read permission for that directory.
Try `ls -la /vol/mynfs/.` and look at the output for `.`, does your user or group have read access?
<sub>You can learn to read the permissions [here](http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/)</sub>

If you have execute access but not read you will be able to open the folder and its subdirectories but not be able to list them (your exact issue). [Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened)
You can fix this issue by running (may need to be root/use `sudo` if you don't own the folder);

```
chmod u+r /vol/mynfs/.
```

Which will add read permissions for the user on that folder.

<sub>The extra `/.` in the commands might be needed if it's a symlink, I don't know.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I also tried this case.

**Solution 1**

In my case, I am using QNAP NAS Server.

My NAS Share folder name is 'mynfs'

ssh to QNAP NAS Server and chmod 750 mynfs

```
chmod 750 /share/NFSv=4/mynfs
```

After NFS Server side chmod setting, My client side nfs can shows all files and directory, now.

**Solution 2**

This solution is modify client side /etc/fstab. Below example, 10.0.0.254 is my QNAP NAS Server.

```
10.0.0.254:/mynfs     /vol/mynfs     nfs     defaults        0       0
```

modify to

```
10.0.0.254:/mynfs    /vol/mynfs     nfs     relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,local_lock=none  0       0
```

After modified /etc/fstab and mount /vol/mynfs again. The files was appear in the /vol/mynfs.

Comment: Your answer is rather about how to configure a nfs export in general, but no answer to my question. I think this is why someone down voted your answer.

Comment: It's ok! Your problem is exactly my question, but no one can provide a useful solution. I found a solution until I succeeded. Of course, I must share with others and help me take notes myself. I cannot answer why, but I can answer how make them always visible, ^_^!